# English idiom of "想入非非"

Tags: translation, meaning, idioms

There is a chinese idiom called `想入非非`:

> to indulge in fantasy

Is there is an english idiom that is similar to this?

Searching gave me this strange "idiom":

> allow one's fancy to run wild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

是非
right and wrong

是是非非
right and wrong

非非之想
wishful thinking

想入非非
indulge in flights of fancy (flights = 量词）

是谁一直在让他想入非非的？
Who has been putting ideas in his head?

> William Shakespeare’s The Tempest in Act IV, Scene 1.
>
> **Prospero:** You do look, my son, in a moved sort,
> As if you were
> dismay’d: be cheerful, sir.
> Our revels now are ended. These our actors,
> As I foretold you, were all spirits and
> Are melted into air, into thin air:
> And, like the baseless fabric of this vision,
> The cloud-capp’d towers, the gorgeous palaces,
> The solemn temples, the great globe itself,
> Ye all which it inherit, shall dissolve
> And, like this insubstantial pageant faded,
> Leave not a rack behind. **We are such stuff
>
> As dreams are made on, and our little life
>
> Is rounded with a sleep.**

Just thought I'd try and squeeze 想入非非 into Prospero's mouth!

We are such stuff as dreams are made on, and our little life is rounded with a sleep.
我们就是想入非非的材料而我们的生活在睡眠里休止。

Answer (score 1):

#### Let your imagination run wild

> take your entire process at your own pace [Source](https://diymfa.com/writing/let-your-imagination-run-wild)

Many websites show that this chinese idiom is similar to the one above:

- [Purple culture](https://www.purpleculture.net/dictionary-details/?word=%E6%83%B3%E5%85%A5%E9%9D%9E%E9%9D%9E)
- [Approachinese](http://approachinese.com/dict/zh2en/%E6%83%B3%E5%85%A5%E9%9D%9E%E9%9D%9E/)
- [omgchinese](https://www.omgchinese.com/dictionary/chinese/%E6%83%B3%E5%85%A5%E9%9D%9E%E9%9D%9E)

Answer (score 1):

> 想入非非、(安身立命)等詞語，它們源自對**佛經**的翻譯

additionally, according to [Sir TL Tang (a Hong Kong professor)](https://www.law.cuhk.edu.hk/app/the-sir-tl-yang-society/),

> 「想入非非」（是胡思亂想），英文是to allow the fancy to run wild。不過這些翻譯不如原文般用字精練和生動

> http://rthk9.rthk.hk/elearning/yangtl/studyroom_topic7_p2.htm

> `as an example•`  we will allow our fancy to run wild •(
> 我們胡思亂想， 想入非非)
> [from this google book](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=7jJrkzEj8qAC&pg=PA41&dq=to%20allow%20the%20fancy%20to%20run%20wild&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidq_Wmud74AhUFp1YBHTJDClcQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=to%20allow%20the%20fancy%20to%20run%20wild&f=false)

[there is also a page in this google book](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=pWFsEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT145&dq=to%20allow%20the%20fancy%20to%20run%20wild&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGg-jSwt74AhXemVYBHQapCFc4ChDoAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=to%20allow%20the%20fancy%20to%20run%20wild&f=false)

Comment: also referring to 胡思亂想。https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=kuozEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA265&dq=to+allow+the+fancy+to+run+wild&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidq_Wmud74AhUFp1YBHTJDClcQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=to%20allow%20the%20fancy%20to%20run%20wild&f=false